# Force iron-router to get back an ready from waitOn

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Currently it seems not to be possible to force a ready() state in the route. For example:
I have a waitOn on 2 subscribtions. One of them returns a Meteor.Error - now the route will be in the loading-state with no ending. 
Is there a recommend way to tell iron-router "waitOn until subscribtion is ready OR subscribtion fails with an error" ?

**Edit:**

To explain my special case:
The waitOn is for a route which is for searching. The search arguments are "what" and "where". In "where" I have a plan String Address and need to convert it to a geo coordinate. For this I use the googlemaps converter on the Serverside (because its Sync). When no address was found I need to get back a error a lá "This address must be wrong". For this I need the functionality to get back an error.

When I do it like David Weldon said I need to do this step in the waitOn method but the Client-Side googlemaps converter is not Sync - instead its async so this would not work.

Answer (score 2):

### General Recommendations

It's okay for your publishers to throw errors, but those conditions should **only** be hit if the client does the wrong thing. In other words, you are solving the wrong problem - you should only subscribe when you know the publisher will not throw an error. Let's look at an example:

Suppose your route needs to subscribe to `newPosts` and `postsForSuperuser`. Assume that the `postsForSuperuser` publisher will throw an error if the user isn't a superuser. It's now the client's job not to let that happen. The `waiton` definition could look like:

```js
waitOn: function() {
  var subs = [Meteor.subscribe('newPosts')];

  if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['superuser']))
    subs.push(Meteor.subscribe('postsForSuperuser'));

  return subs;
}
```

Because we are conditionally adding the `postsForSuperuser` subscription, we don't give the publisher the opportunity to throw an error.

### Your specific use case

You case is a little more tricky, because mechanically the client is doing the correct thing but the user input may happen to be bad. In this case, I don't think throwing an error is appropriate. Here are some recommendations:

1. Avoid the problem by checking the address via a method call prior to changing the route.
2. If an address is found to be invalid, have the publish function immediately `return this.ready()`. This will prevent your route from failing, but you'll be left assuming that the reason you have no data is because of the address. If that's a valid assumption (i.e. it's the only possible reason for failure), then your router could deal with this by using a `dataNotFound` hook.
3. If you need to explicitly identify the cause of the error, have a close look at the 'counts' example from [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe). You can declare a client-only collection called `addressErrors` and then call `this.added` with a dynamically created document describing the cause of the error. The implementation of this is a little more tricky, and probably worthy of a separate question if you get stuck. I'd see if the first two make sense before attempting it.

Comment: This looks nice - but does not help me out. I edited my post to show you the real problem I have (I need a async function before waitOn arguments or an server-side sync method but then I need to return if there is an error.)

Comment: Okay I updated the answer with some more suggestions - hopefully one of those works for you.

Comment: Nice input - again. I wi check this today and will give you a feedback.

Comment: Hi David and sorry for late response but wasnt able to test your 3 points. To Point 1: I can add a function (like onBeforeAction) to a route but this cant be async as I udnerstood ? And also - as I know - there is no way to call a method which is executed on server side and tell the router to wait until the result is there, isnt it ?    To Point 2: This is what I updated and do now - so the subscirbtion is "ready" but I dont know why: Was there an error or not ? So this will not rly solve the problem but has to be done! (thanks for this).

Comment: Point 3: I read the documentation and this seems to be an option ... if there is smth possible like to add a "added" or "changed" callback to the subscribtion with the content of its. Then I could tell the subscriobt that some content was added (for example an error code) and this content I would be able to read on client side - but is this still possible in this way ? There is no "subscribtion" callback - instead it seems jsut to have a Collection callback, right ? I think this is not the best solution but maybe the only one which will work yet ...

Comment: My assumption for (1) was that whatever form the user filled out prior to displaying the geo data could simply validate the data with an async method call and only change the route if the call succeeded. In theory you can validate the data in an `onBeforeAction` hook using my code from [this issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/294). It works for me in iron-router `0.9.4` but didn't in `1.0` when last I tried.